Как отправить личное сообщение человеку в aiogram
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на Инлайн-кнопку Помощь сообщение приходило мне, а не пользователям, которые общаются с ним
Например, чтобы приходил его username
@router.message(F.data == 'username')
async def username(Callback : CallbackQuery):
   await callback.message.answer('username')


Вот так:
@router.message(F.data == 'username')
async def username(call: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id="ТУТ ТВОЙ ID", text=call.message.chat.username)

не забудь в chat_id прописать свой ID
